# Why you can't you monitor "Http Request Execution time", "Http Request Rate and "Http requests in execution queue" from application insights?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to setup Azure Application Insights to monitor the performance counters for the following metrics for an ASP.NET Core Web App and Web API hosted in Azure App Services:

1. HTTP request execution time
2. HTTP request rate
3. HTTP request in execution queue

I'm fairly sure Application Insights is configured properly since I can see other metrics showing up in the portal. Is there some reason these particular metrics don't seem show up? I've even tried taking one of the default ASP.NET Core templates and deploying with Application Insights and I'm still not seeing these counters update. Are these counter's just not available for applications hosted in Azure or for ASP.NET Core applications? I did try the latest Web App template that comes with VS 2017 Update 2.

Answer (score 1):

These are available, but they're tucked away. To add them, do the following:

1. Navigate to your AppInsights Overview blade. Click on the Metrics Explorer button.

[image: Metrics Explorer button in the App Insights Overview blade]

2. On the Metrics Explorer blade, click the Edit link to add additional metrics.

[image]

3. On the Metrics blade, expand the Performance Counter node. You'll see the three you're looking for there.

[image]

Comment: I know where the metrics are in the UI. The problem is they don't update when I run the application. I can see the other metrics updating, but not these.

Answer (score 1):

When you say other metrics do show up - which ones specifically you mean?
The metrics you mentioned (HTTP requests,...) are collected by the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector module of the SDK, and this module is available only if you are running the .net core app against full framework.